# Consultas preparadas en php con mvc?

Tags: php, mvc

Resulta que tengo una base de datos con una tabla usuario y los campos nombre, clave, correo y rol. Estoy aprendiendo a hacer un sistema de ventas con php usando el patron modelo vista controlador. en la carpeta modelo tengo una clase conexion:

```html
<?php

    class Conexion
    {
        public static function conectar(){
            $servidor='localhost'; $usuario='root'; $contrasenia=''; $db='ventas';
            $conn=new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$contrasenia,$db);
    
            /*Con la funcion ping podemos saber si se conecto de manera correcta a la base de datos.
            si devuelve 1 esta conectada, de lo contrario hay un error de conexión. */
            //echo $conn->ping();
    
            return $conn;
        }
        
    }
    
    
?>
```

Luego tengo una clase usuario:

```html
<?php

/* Creación de la clase Usuario */
class usuario{


    private $db;
    private $usuario=array();

    public function __constructor()
    {
        require_once('conexion.php');
        $this->db=Conexion::conectar();
        $this->usuario=array();

    }
    
    public function validarUsuario($nombre, $clave){
        
        $this->nombre=filter_var($nombre,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $this->clave=filter_var($clave,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $stmt=$this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usunombre=? AND usupassword=?');
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $this->nombre,$this->clave);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        
        return $stmt;
        $stmt->close();
        $this->conexion->close();
    }


}

?>
```

Luego en modelo tengo un archivo validar usuario:

```html
<?php

require_once ('../modelo/usuario.php');

$user=new usuario();
$usuario=$user->validarUsuario($_POST['usuario'],$_POST['password']);

require_once ('../vista/menu.php');

?>
```

Y por ultimo en archivo vista tengo esto:

```html
    <form action="controlador/validarUsuario.php" class="frm" id="frm" method="post">
```

El archivo saca este error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\wamp64\www\Ventas\modelo\usuario.php on line 22

Bueno el caso es que tengo conocimientos de php pero quiero aprender por mi cuenta a codificar usando MVC. Por lo tanto quiero saber que estoy fallando. Agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo que use hace mucho tiempo, usando PDO...

```
<?php 

// Obtener usuarios de la base de datos
class Usuario extends Conexion
{
    // Atributos
    private $usuario;
    private $pass;
    // Retorno los datos
    public function getUsuario(){
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    public function getPass(){
        return $this->pass;
    }

    // Obtengo los datos
    public function Login($conexion, $usuario, $pass){
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
        $this->pass = $pass;

        // Consulta para obtener los datos
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = :pass LIMIT 1');
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':usuario' => $usuario,
            ':pass' => $pass
        ));
        $result = $statement->fetch();

        return $result;
    }

}

?>
```